# How to cast shadow onto image planes with alpha?

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

[image]

The cube doesn't cast shadow on the leaves but it does on the plane/floor. And the leaves don't cast shadow onto themselves, unlike the one on the top right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

..my bad, forgot to plug-in DiffuseBSDF. It's working now.

[image]